# Rails app: has_one relationship seems to be working, but can't access records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two models, site and robots_file. Site has_one robots file and robots_file belongs to site.

From the site model, I can create a new record on the robots_file table.  But I can't actually access that new record.  So, if I'm in console, I can do this:

```
Site.last.create_robots_file
```

and it will create that necessary record on the robots_file table.  But if try this:

```
Site.last.robots_files.first
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `robots_files' for #<Site:0x007fcccaff2f28>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a has one relationship, you can't access "robots_files", you should access "robot_file"

```
Site.last.robot_file
```

Hope it helps!